# Returning uint Value from Char in gawk

Tags: awk, ord

I'm trying to get value of an ASCII char I receive via RS232 to convert them into binary like values.

Example:

```
0xFF-->########
0x01-->       #
0x02-->      #
...
```

My Problem is to get the value of ASCII chars higher than 127.

Test-Code to get the int value:
`echo -e "\xFF" | gawk -l ordchr -e '{printf("%c : %i", ord($0),ord($0))}'`
Return:
`� : -1`

Test-Code 2:
`echo -e "\x61" | gawk -l ordchr -e '{printf("%c : %i", ord($0),ord($0))}'`
Return:
`a : 97`

So my solution to convert the values into unsigned int, is like this:

```
if(ord($0)<0)
{
    new_char=ord($0)+256;
}
else new_char = ord($0)+0`
```

But I wanted to know if there was a way to cast directly an `int` as `uint` in gawk.

Later I tried to write my own `ord()` function.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\xFF" | awk 'BEGIN {_ord_init()}
{
    printf("%s : %d\n", $0, ord($0))
}

function _ord_init(    i, t)
{
    for (i=0; i <= 255; i++) {
         t = sprintf("%c", i)
        _ord_[t] = i
    }
}

function ord(str,    c)
{
    # only first character is of interest
    c = substr(str, 1, 1)
    return _ord_[c]
}'
```

`0xFF` returns:

```
� : 0
```

`0x61` returns:

```
a : 97
```

Can someone explain me the behavior?

I'm using:
`GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4-p1, GNU MP 6.1.1)`

Comment: for this line at `_ord_init(…)` ::::::::::::::::: combine both lines within each loop cycle to :::::::::::::::::::::  `_ord_[ sprintf("%c",  4^5 * 54  + i ) ] = i` — that should give you an array of byte ordinal values `[0, 255]` regardless of your locale (unless you're on something like `EBCDIC`). If your `awk` couldn't handle `"%c"` above `0x7FFF`, like some variants of `busybox`, then change that offset value to `8^4` instead

Answer (score 1):

> But I wanted to know if there was a way to cast directly an int as uint in gawk.

Actually, any string in awk is, in the end, a number.

> Strings are converted to numbers and numbers are converted to strings,
> if the context of the awk program demands it. [...] A string is
> converted to a number by interpreting any numeric prefix of the string
> as numerals: "2.5" converts to 2.5, "1e3" converts to 1,000, and
> "25fix" has a numeric value of 25. Strings that can’t be interpreted
> as valid numbers convert to zero. [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html)

Let's make a quick test:

```
BEGIN { 
   print 0xff
   print 0xff + 0
   print 0xff +0.0
   print "0xff"
}

# 255
# 255
# 255
# 0xff
```

So, any `hex` is automatically interpreted as `uint`. Casting a `int` to `uint` is a tricky question: generally, you should convert the modulus of the `int` to hex, then add the sign bit as MSB (that is, if the number is non-positive). But you should not need to do so in awk.

Remember that conversion is made as a call to `sprintf()` and you may control it via the `CONVFMT` variable:

> `CONVFMT`
>
> A string that controls the conversion of numbers to strings
> (see section [Conversion of Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conversion.html)). It works by being
> passed, in effect, as the first argument to the sprintf() function
> (see section [String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)). Its default value is
> "%.6g". CONVFMT was introduced by the POSIX standard. [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html)

Remember that locale settings may affect the way the conversion is performed, especially with the decimal separator. For more, see [this, which is out of scope](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Locale-influences-conversions.html).

---

> Can someone explain me the behavior?

I can't actually reproduce it, but I suspect this line of code:

```
# only first character is of interest
c = substr(str, 1, 1)
```

In your example, the first char is always `0` and the output should always be the same. I'm testing this [online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_awk_online.php).

I'll make another example of mine:

```
BEGIN {
    a = 0xFF
    b = 0x61
    printf("a: %d %f %X %s %c\n", a,a,a,a,a)
    printf("b: %d %f %X %s %c\n", b,b,b,b,b)
}

# a: 255 255.000000 FF 255 ÿ
# b: 97 97.000000 61 97 a
```